How to rotate cairo circle (volume button) on mouse motion event in gtk4?
I'm trying to create a Volume (Cairo circle) button in gtk4. which can be rotate by mouse motion event. By clicking anywhere on the button and rotating it, the value 1-100 will be output. Tried a lot, maybe it's beyond my knowledge.
Below is what i tried, with the mouse pointer on it, the circle is rotating. But the main problem is that the circle can't be rotated properly by clicking anywhere on the circle; the volume indicator point(sub circle), moving directly to the mouse pointer and can't figure out how to get the output in integer format. Can anyone check it?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>

float angel = 0.00;

//rotate the surface
cairo_surface_t *Rotate(cairo_surface_t *image, int degrees )
{
    int              w, h;
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_surface_t* tgt;

    w = cairo_image_surface_get_width (image);
    h = cairo_image_surface_get_height (image);

    tgt = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h);
    cr = cairo_create(tgt);

    cairo_translate (cr, w/2, h/2);
    cairo_rotate (cr, degrees* M_PI/180);
    cairo_scale  (cr, w/w, h/h);
    cairo_translate (cr, -0.5*w, -0.5*h);

    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, image, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return tgt;
}

//draw circle
cairo_surface_t *draw_circle (int width, int height)
{
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_surface_t* tgt;

    tgt = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
    cr = cairo_create(tgt);

    int radius;
    if (width < height)
    radius = width/2;
    else
    radius = height/2;

    cairo_move_to (cr, width/2 + radius, height/2);
    cairo_arc (cr, width/2, height/2, radius, 0.0, 2 * M_PI);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0);
    cairo_fill_preserve (cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_stroke (cr); 


    cairo_arc (cr, width*93/100, height/2, radius*5/100, 0.0, 2 * M_PI);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.9, 0.0, 1.0);
    cairo_fill_preserve (cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_stroke (cr); 

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return tgt;
}


static void
draw_function (GtkDrawingArea *darea,
               cairo_t        *cr,
               int             width,
               int             height,
               gpointer        user_data)
{

    cairo_surface_t *surF = draw_circle(width, height);

    cairo_surface_t *rot = Rotate(surF, angel);

    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, rot, 0, 0);
    cairo_surface_destroy(rot);

    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_surface_destroy(surF);

    //draw start and last indicator line
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 1.0, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width (cr, 3.5);

    cairo_move_to (cr, 5, height-5);
    cairo_line_to (cr, width*13/100, height*87/100);

    cairo_move_to (cr, width-5, height-5);
    cairo_line_to (cr, width*87/100, height*87/100);

     cairo_stroke(cr); 
}


void pointer_motion_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x, 
                           gdouble y, 
                           gpointer user_data)
{
     GdkModifierType state = gtk_event_controller_get_current_event_state(gesture);

     if (state & GDK_BUTTON1_MASK) {
         g_print ("mouse pointer %0.0f  %0.0f\n", x, y);

         int width = gtk_widget_get_width(user_data);
         int height = gtk_widget_get_height(user_data);

         int cx = width/2, cy = height/2; //center of the object
         int mx = x, my = y;  // current mouse cursor position

         float new_angle = atan2f(my - cy, mx - cx);
         float deg = (new_angle * 180 / M_PI);
         angel = deg;
         printf ("%f\n", deg);

     }
     gtk_widget_queue_draw(user_data);
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));


  GtkWidget *darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_width (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea), 350);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_height (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea), 350);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea),
                                  draw_function,
                                  NULL, NULL);

  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), darea);

    GtkEventController *gesture_pos;
    gesture_pos = gtk_event_controller_motion_new ();
    gtk_widget_add_controller (darea, (GtkEventController *)gesture_pos);
    gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase((GtkEventController  *)gesture_pos, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE);
    g_signal_connect (gesture_pos, "motion", G_CALLBACK (pointer_motion_event), darea);

  gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}


It looks like you can capture the window coordinates of the mouse click and then translate the coordinates to the position of the dial and rotate to that position. Your press-and-hold rotations output the mouse coordinates of the mouse each step along the way. Why not just do the same thing for a click? Get the coordinates and then rotate to it?. To help with this why not define 100 increments of rotations and map the window coordinates to each increment. That would then allow you to get 0-99 out of a given coordinate within the window. (and purple??)

My solution is to add another EventController and a corresponding function.
The EventController should be implemented as follows:
   GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture), 0);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(darea,(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture)));
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_event), NULL);

The corresponding function would then look like this:
void click_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x,
                           gdouble y,
                           gpointer user_data)

{
         GtkWidget *widget = gtk_event_controller_get_widget(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture));

         int width = gtk_widget_get_width(widget);
         int height = gtk_widget_get_height(widget);

         int cx = width/2, cy = height/2; //center of the object
         int mx = x, my = y;  // current mouse cursor position

        float new_angle = atan2f(my - cy, mx - cx);
        float deg = (new_angle * 180 / M_PI);
        angel = deg;
        printf ("%f\n", deg);


     gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
}

Unfortunately, the use of user-data does not work here. Therefore, the way is via gtk-event-controller-get-widget(...)

I tried that, but the result is the same. As I clicked, the volume indicator(sub circle) moved to the mouse pointer, which I didn't want. I want to rotate it by clicking anywhere on the circle but the indicator should not always follow the mouse pointer.
user-data will work, pass widget to cb--
`g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_event), darea);`


I didn't quite understand the question? Here is another version that hopefully fits this time :-).
An additional global variable:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>

float angel = 0.00;
int stop = 0;


Then three more functions:
gboolean event_callback(gpointer widget) {
        static int value = 0;
        angel = angel +3.6;
if (angel >= 360 )
                angel = 0;
        printf ("%i \n", (int)(angel/3.6));

     gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);

     if (stop == 0)
        return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
     else
       {
        stop = 0;
        return FALSE;
       }
}

void end_event(GtkEventController *gesture,
                                gdouble x,
                                gdouble y,
                                gpointer user_data)
{
        stop = 1;

}


void click_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x,
                           gdouble y,
                           gpointer user_data)

{
         GtkWidget *widget = gtk_event_controller_get_widget(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture));


         g_timeout_add(100,event_callback,widget);

}

And the second EventController:
GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture), 0);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(darea,(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture)));
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (gesture,"released",G_CALLBACK(end_event),NULL);

Man can certainly make this easier, but the principle should have become clear now.
Corresponding to the comment here is the customized function "click-event".
void click_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x,
                           gdouble y,
                           gpointer user_data)

{
         GtkWidget *widget = gtk_event_controller_get_widget(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture));
         angel = angel +3.6;
         if (angel >= 360 )
                angel = 0;
         printf ("%i \n", (int)(angel/3.6));

         gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);

}

Greetings

It's not working properly, if you press and hold the mouse button it keeps rotating.

Yes, that's how I programmed it specially. In order for the point to move forward only by one unit, you simply have to use the click-event function instead of the timer. I deliver equally :-)

It didn't work as well as expected. You can check out the Jetaudio Music Player android app. This app's volume button is an example of what i want.

So now the last variant. Makes real fun to try out the different possibilities. You finally learn something.

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>

float angel = 0.00;
int stop = 1;
int old_x = 0;

//rotate the surface
cairo_surface_t *Rotate(cairo_surface_t *image, int degrees )
{
    int              w, h;
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_surface_t* tgt;

    w = cairo_image_surface_get_width (image);
    h = cairo_image_surface_get_height (image);

    tgt = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h);
    cr = cairo_create(tgt);

    cairo_translate (cr, w/2, h/2);
    cairo_rotate (cr, degrees* M_PI/180);
    cairo_scale  (cr, w/w, h/h);
    cairo_translate (cr, -0.5*w, -0.5*h);

    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, image, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return tgt;
}

//draw circle
cairo_surface_t *draw_circle (int width, int height)
{
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_surface_t* tgt;

    tgt = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
    cr = cairo_create(tgt);

    int radius;
    if (width < height)
    radius = width/2;
    else
    radius = height/2;

    cairo_move_to (cr, width/2 + radius, height/2);
    cairo_arc (cr, width/2, height/2, radius, 0.0, 2 * M_PI);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0);
    cairo_fill_preserve (cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_stroke (cr);


    cairo_arc (cr, width*93/100, height/2, radius*5/100, 0.0, 2 * M_PI);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.9, 0.0, 1.0);
    cairo_fill_preserve (cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_stroke (cr);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return tgt;
}


static void
draw_function (GtkDrawingArea *darea,
               cairo_t        *cr,
               int             width,
               int             height,
               gpointer        user_data)
{

    cairo_surface_t *surF = draw_circle(width, height);

    cairo_surface_t *rot = Rotate(surF, angel);

    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, rot, 0, 0);
    cairo_surface_destroy(rot);

    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_surface_destroy(surF);

    //draw start and last indicator line
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 1.0, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width (cr, 3.5);

    cairo_move_to (cr, 5, height-5);
    cairo_line_to (cr, width*13/100, height*87/100);

    cairo_move_to (cr, width-5, height-5);
    cairo_line_to (cr, width*87/100, height*87/100);

     cairo_stroke(cr);
}

void pointer_motion_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x,
                           gdouble y,
                           gpointer user_data)
{
   if (stop == 0)
   {
     if ((int)x > old_x) 
     {
         old_x = x;
             angel = angel +3.6;
        if (angel >= 360 )
            angel = 0;
            printf ("%i \n", (int)(angel/3.6));
     
         gtk_widget_queue_draw(user_data);
     }
     if ((int)x < old_x )
     {
         old_x = x; 
             angel = angel -3.6;
        if (angel <= 0)
            angel = 360;
            printf ("%i \n", (int)(angel/3.6));
     
         gtk_widget_queue_draw(user_data);

     }
   }
}

void end_event(GtkEventController *gesture,
                gdouble x,
                gdouble y,
                gpointer user_data)
{
    stop = 1;

}


void click_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x,
                           gdouble y,
                           gpointer user_data)

{
  old_x = x;
  stop = 0;
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));


  GtkWidget *darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_width (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea), 350);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_height (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea), 350);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea),
                                  draw_function,
                                  NULL, NULL);

  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), darea);

      GtkEventController *gesture_pos;
      gesture_pos = gtk_event_controller_motion_new ();
      gtk_widget_add_controller (darea, (GtkEventController *)gesture_pos);
      gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase((GtkEventController  *)gesture_pos, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE);
      g_signal_connect (gesture_pos, "motion", G_CALLBACK (pointer_motion_event), darea);

    GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture), 0);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(darea,(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture)));
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (gesture,"released",G_CALLBACK(end_event),NULL);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}

It still can't be blinked when clicking on it, but that was probably not the requirement :-).
Greetings
P.S:
If you divide a circle into 100 parts, then it means that each step is 3.6 degrees. If this is too much "jerky", then please change the following:
angle = angle+1.0;

and
angle = angle-1.0;

or an even smaller number.
However, I cannot see a discrepancy between the movement of the mouse and the rotation.
The inclusion of the Y-axis would be unfavourable in my opinion, because here two movements (horizontal and vertical) would be mapped to a rotation, which could easily confuse or overwhelm the user.

It moves somewhat well but not smooth. It does not rotate in accordance with the mouse pointer. The volume indicator (sub circle) rotates uncontrollably. Perhaps the old_y value also needs to be calculated.
